# Update table with join vs WHERE in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with 500k rows, and I have a stored procedure in which I have created a temp table which has a column which is equivalent to the primary key of the actual table.

I want to update my table, and I have tried these two ways. I would like to know which one is better in terms of performance.

```
UPDATE LRD --Commented By Vivek
SET LRD.Status = 2            
FROM Log_ReminderDetail LRD            
JOIN @Result R ON LRD.ReminderPK = R.ReminderPK
```

or

```
UPDATE Log_ReminderDetail      --Commented By Vivek      
SET Status = 2            
WHERE ReminderPK IN (SELECT ReminderPK FROM @Result)
```

I don't see any major difference in the execution plan of both.

[image]

[image]

Comment: They will effectively be the same if there are no repeats in Result. However, if there are going to be larger numbers in there, you should use a #temp table (probably with a primary key), rather than a table variable. Table variables do not have statistics associated with them, so SQL Server just guesses how many rows there are (e.g., 1).

Comment: @seanb thank you, please add this as your answer